# jquery, задержка анимации

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код, при котором выкатывается поиск и скрывается один элемент, но при повторном нажатии, когда поиск скрывается обратно, `div` элемент, который скрылся, появляется сразу, от этого прыгает весь сайт; как это исправить?

```
$('.search_1').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search').click(function() {
      $('.search_1').stop().animate({width: 'toggle'});
         if ($('.order').css('display') !== 'none'){
    $('.order').css('display','none');}
        else{
        $('.order').css('display','block');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: С решением такой ситуации поможет "очередь".  Подробнее здесь: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.order').css('display','block');
}, 800);
```